# How to realize vma backup with proxmox from command line?

Tags: backup, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, proxmox

I have a problem with my proxmox node, I have to reconfigure the server disks,
since having them badly configured, I cannot perform snapshots quickly since they are badly mounted and the io is very slow, therefore, I have migrated all my machines out of the server, with the intention of I compress virtual disks myself using the proxmox vma format together with lzo compression, but I can't find anywhere, how to make vma backups via command line.

Does anyone know how vma backups are made by command line?

Comment: i suggest you to use forum.proxmox.com its i think easier

Comment: Good Idea, thank you for response!